# Can we get a human-readable legally-useless sidebar for the terms of service?

Tags: feature-request, legal, terms-of-service

Stack Exchange's [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) has a Legally Useless Summary on the left sidebar explaining succinctly what each section of the policy says and how it affects the user. Unfortunately, the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) does not.

Can we get one there? The Terms of Service are arguably just as important as the privacy policy, and while I've taken the time to read through the ToS, it would have been much easier and clearer if there were a human-readable legalese-free version on the left sidebar like there is for the privacy policy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m especially sentimental about these, since that page was the first thing I did as a semi-employee here.  I was a long-time user, but re-doing that policy (which included the summary) was a consulting gig I did right before eventually deciding to work here.

So, I’d love to see one added there, but it actually takes a fair bit of work, and  involves some hassle and back and forth with lawyers to ensure it’s aligned with the intended meanings, etc. (Turns out legal docs are *supposed* to speak for themselves.)  And that’s all got to get re-done when changes happen.

Long story short, we’ll probably add one, but it probably won’t be soon; most likely we’d attack this the next time we make meaningful changes to the ToS.

Comment: "Turns out legal docs are *supposed* to speak for themselves." Ho ho ho! You kill me. (And I'm the kinda guy that reads the whole thing... then adds the URL to [a change detection addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sitedelta/) for later reference.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, yes, I also giggled when they told me that.